# How do I delete all of my Google Contacts with a certain label?

Tags: google-contacts

I've synced all the employees' contacts of my previous work to my Google Contacts. Luckily they're all labeled with the company name, but I can't seem to find a way to deleted/archive/hide them all. Only how to delete the label itself.

Comment: This question has been bumped by a Community user 16 times. On October 30, 2023, a [discussion](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/88163) on [meta] about this site research policy was declared resolved. Among other things, the resolution states that this site is not a help desk. Please check out the [tour] to learn the ropes of this site and [ask] to learn about the quality standards for asking questions. Please note that the posted notice includes a link explaining why questions might be closed and the close reason.

Comment: @Rubén This seems like a case where a "beginner […] has made the most basic level of effort to understand the issue". OP included some information about their attempts to solve the problem, so it's not so trivial as to be answered by simply opening the webapp. It should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was embarrassingly simple; now I understand why no one had asked this question before: 
You select all people with that label, and click delete.

Comment: Not all the questions should be answered. Please read [answer].